# Apostol Limit Proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality

This is an interesting proof of the product limit law.  I can see the squeeze theorem but how do you work out the step when applying the triangle-CS inequality with norms?  Will this work for any $n$ dimensional vector?  Thanks very much!

$$f(x) \cdot g(x) - b \cdot c = [f(x) - b] \cdot [g(x) - c] + b\cdot[g(x) - c] + c\cdot[f(x) - b]$$
Now we use the triangle inequality and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to obtain
$$0 \le \Vert f(x) \cdot g(x) - b\cdot c\Vert \le \Vert f(x)-b\Vert \cdot\Vert g(x)-c\Vert + \Vert b\Vert \cdot\Vert g(x)-c\Vert + \Vert c \Vert \cdot\Vert f(x)-b\Vert$$

Comment: Some details are required. What are $f,g$ and $b,c$? Where are the $n$ dimensional vectors?

Comment: f and g are general functions.  say for example these are vectors in n dimensional space, x=(x1,x2....xn)

Comment: the norm is greater than or equal to 0 since it involves a square and then you apply Cauchy-Schwarz and Triangle Inequality both